# How to add my course Slug before lecture in url path?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i'm currently doing a project for my homework, which i didn't managed to see something like this to fix my problem.

I have 2 models with `Course` and `CourseLecture` name. and i'm using `getPathAttribute` in my class base on a tutorial in internet.

in my Course Model i'm using getPathAttribute like this :

```
public function getPathAttribute()
{
    return "/clientside/instructor/courses/$this->slug";
}
```

and in my CourseLecture Model :

```
public function getPathAttribute()
{
    return "/clientside/instructor/courses/{course}/lectures/$this->slug";
}
```

I need to put my course slug to this getPathAttribute like :

`http://url.com/clientside/instructor/courses/php/lectures/one`

also my `CourseLecture` is using `course_id` and i've got a relationship between them which, they're `belongsTo' and`HasMany'. so how can i add course slug base on this structor in this path?

Also for this homework, i'm using Vue.js/Laravel. and it's a spa. i've tagged vue.js bcs if there's any solution to fix this via router, I will be happy to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically grab `course slug` from the `course()` relationship defined on the `CourseLecture` model. See below:

In `CourseLecture` model:

```php
protected $appends = ['path'];

// relationship
public function course()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}

public function getPathAttribute()
{
    return "/clientside/instructor/courses/{$this->course->slug}/lectures/$this->slug";
}
```

Comment: it worked man... Thanks. since i'm doing things in different way, i never saw someone use `$appends`. can u explain me about it or link me to any reference?

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. `appends` let's you add attributes (always) to eloquent models without you need to ask for it.

Comment: You can read more about `appends` here https://laraveldaily.com/why-use-appends-with-accessors-in-eloquent/

Comment: well, then, thanks for your help and response my friend.